# Wanted to know why my querySelector in js doesn't work when fetching data from an input field

Tags: javascript

Don't really understand why my `querySelector` isn't working. When I substitute `querySelector` with `getElementByClass`, it works, I just dont understand why it wouldn't work with `querySelector`.

```js
function stdCalculator() {
  let stdHeight = document.querySelector(".stdHeight")[0].value
  let stdWeight = document.querySelector("stdWeight")[0].value
  let stdDsply = document.querySelector(".stdReslt")[0]
  let stdBmi = (703 * Number(stdWeight)) / Number(stdHeight) *
    Number(stdHeight)
  return stdDsply.innerHTML = stdBmi;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Your Height In Inches</p>
  <input class="stdHeight" type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <p>Your Weight in Pounds</p>
  <input class="stdWeight" type="text">
</div>
<p class="stdReslt">BMI</p>
<button onclick="stdCalculator()">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: `querySelector` returns *one* element only. `querySelectorAll` returns multiple.

Comment: Note also the typo in `document.querySelector("stdWeight")`. You're missing the period before the class name